# IIS 6 is no longer installed after computer restart

Tags: iis-6, windows-server-2003-r2

I was doing some maintenance on a build server at work and I changed some various settings (registry settings for custom applications, user permissions, etc.), then I restarted the machine. When the machine came back up, I couldn't access a website that is hosted on this machine, so I went digging around. It seems as if IIS6 was somehow uninstalled, which I know I didn't do.

My question is: What would cause this? I've tried to reinstall it, uninstall it, reinstall it again, and nothing has changed. I still have a blank IIS Manager application (inetmgr), and no way to access these websites.

BTW, the computer is running Windows Server 2003 R2 x64 Service Pack 2.

Answer (score 0):

> I changed some various settings
>   (registry settings for custom
>   applications, user permissions, etc.),

So, what did you do there? Did you plan it in advance and follow the written plan, or did you wing it?

Do you have a backup of the metabase? You could try restoring that now that you have IIS back.

I'm assuming by saying "blank IIS Manager application" that IIS is at least running, but with nothing in it?

Comment: When I browse INetMgr, it doesn't make a connection to the local machine (localhost), and when I try to connect to it, it tells me "This computer is not running Internet Information Services version 4 or higher." 

As far as the registry settings, it was all for custom apps and DLLs that we have on our build machine. The user permissions was to grant one account Admin rights.

Comment: You could spend a lot of time figuring this out, or restore from a backup taken shortly before the changes you made. I would tend towards the latter, particularly in a production environment. Then, once the IIS issue is resolved, you could re-try the change you made and see if there's any IIS impact.

For the former path, is the W3 service even running? Is there anything in the application and system logs that tells you what the machine thinks happened? There should be. Post that info, if you want to troubleshoot this.

Comment: This machine is a backup (and a VM), so it may not be used, as our 'production' build machine doesn't have any issues.

The W3SVC (World Wide Web Publishing Service) is not present in the services window.

I'll mark this issue as closed because I'm just going to restart from a snapshot take for the VM. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already given up on this, I've seen the same problem before, and it was a permissions problem in the registry.  We don't know how it got into this state, but this key:

```
HKLM\software\microsoft\windows nt\currentversion\svchost
```

needed to have the Administrators group be given Full Control.  Hope this helps, otherwise a restore might be the quickest option (this took a while to figure out).

Comment: I looked into it, but that wasn't the case.